# Add onload to aspx page with master page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side, onload

I need to add an `onload` event to the `body` tag of an aspx page that is using a master page.

I tried the following to the aspx page and the first alert pops up and never gets to the `onload` function.

.aspx page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        alert("here 1");  <-- This pops up
        window.addEventListener('load', load(), false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
        alert("here 2");
        window.attachEvent('onload', load());
    }
    ....
</script>

... page content here ...

<script>
    function load() {   <--- it doesn't stop here
        debugger
        var extenderID = "<%= edContent.ClientID %>";
        alert(extenderID);
        var afu = $find(extenderID + "_ajaxFileUpload");
        alert(afu);
        afu._uploadUrl = "MyProj/AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd";
    }

</script>
```

I am trying to resolve an issue with Ajax HTML Editor Extender when inserting an image (pops up authentication dialog) and read that the issue could be with file upload handler path.

Comment: Remove parentheses `()` from **load()**. It should be `window.addEventListener('load', load, false);`

Comment: Thanks Alex, the load function still doesn't get hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the load listener after the load function declaration:

```
--Init page content

 function load() {   
        debugger
        var extenderID = "<%= edContent.ClientID %>";
        alert(extenderID);
        var afu = $find(extenderID + "_ajaxFileUpload");
        alert(afu);
        afu._uploadUrl = "MyProj/AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd";
    }

-- End page content

if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', load, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', load);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. The load() function now does get hit. Even though now the value of "afu" is displayed in alert box as "undefined", but that's not related to this post. I  marked your response as answer.